# C# GetManifestResourceStream returns null

Tags: c#, .net, stream, embedded-resource

im workin on a C# WinForms application. I need to embed a .dll and i try to "export" this file from Resource to HDD.

Im using the default form Resource...

```
System.IO.Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("FormNamespace.Form1.Newtonsoft_Json");
```

The Filename is Newtonsoft.Json.dll and i tried also:

```
System.IO.Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("FormNamespace.Form1.Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

Both dosn't work. s is always null.
I think im using the wrong way to access the resource but i dont know :(

Would be nice if someone could help me :)

Comment: did you try just Json.dll `System.IO.Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Json.dll");` ?

Comment: Getting the string you pass to GetManifestResourceStream wrong is a *very* common problem.  Which is why Visual Studio has a resource designer, Project + Properties, Resources tab.  You debug it by looking at the actual name, run ildasm.exe on the assembly, double-click the manifest and look at the .mresource directive.  Don't hide executable code in a resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've set correctly the build action to "embedded resource", the problem is most likely the name of the resource.

It should be namespace + file name; have you tried `FormNamespace.Newtonsoft_Json.dll`?

Otherwise, you can try executing the [GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and see what it returns.

Comment: GetManifestResourceName returns: FormNamespace.Properties.Resources.resources ... but dosnt work too

Comment: @zAfLu: are you sure the build action is set correctly?

Comment: Well I'm giving you an upvote: Wrong namespace was exactly my problem (cutting&pasting code between projects)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() then you get a better path to your resource doing the following:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Json.dll");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide all Path to the resource. Example
[DLLNAME or NameSpace].[ResourceName]
If resource located on Res folder then
[DLLNAME or NameSpace].[Res.Resource.txt]